# How to create a new column in an empty dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my code  :

```
dfNbMatchSurface = data.frame()
print(dfNbMatchSurface)
dfNbMatchSurface$test <- "exp"
write.csv(dfNbMatchSurface, file = "NbMatchSurface.csv")
```

And i want to create an empty dataframe with a new test column that is empty and call "exp"

How to do that ?

I've also tried this :

```
dfNbMatchSurface = data.frame()
print(dfNbMatchSurface)
dfNbMatchSurface$test <- NA 
write.csv(dfNbMatchSurface, file = "NbMatchSurface.csv")
```

I have thos error  :

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, test, value = "exp") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Regards and thanks

Comment: What is `exp`?...

Comment: @sotos edited thanks

Comment: You might do this `df <- data.frame(test = NA)`. Please tell us your intended purpose of initializing an empty `data.frame`, maybe we can give better advice then.

Comment: You probably want dfNbMatchSurface$exp<- ""?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `character()` to assign a class to the variable without including values (other classes also work, like `factor()`, `integer()` or `numeric()`).

```
df <- data.frame()
> df
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

df$var1 <- character()
> df
[1] var1
<0 rows> (or row.names with length 0)
```